# Problem With outputStream after 1 download

Tags: spring, spring-boot

After downloading an Excel with HttpServletResponse the second time i tried to download it dosent work.

```
           public void DatosaExcel(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        
                writeHeaderLine();
                writeDataLines();
                 
                ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                workbook.write(outputStream);   
                outputStream.close();

           }
```

```
    @GetMapping("/DescargarExcelEmpleados")
    public void DescargarEmpleados(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = "attachment; filename=empleados.xlsx";
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        productService.DatosaExcel(response);
    }
```

those are my Ctrl and function that calls the excel generator but i cant find a way of solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using Apache POI for Excel work here and also guess that nothing happens when you try to generate it the second time (if there is an error, please provide the log).

This is probably because you didn't close the workbook after write. Always

```
workbook.write(outputStream);
workbook.close(); //<-- Important!!!
```

Comment: Thnaks but i got an error when adding that line of code: that the method close is undefined for the type XSSFWorkbook

Comment: I found to solve changing the version of POI and added ur line of code but i compile it and try it, but keeps breaking after 1 download of the file.

Comment: What happens now? Error?

Comment: it keep working for just once, after that the controler tag doesn't work shows error.

Comment: I guess some other stream is not closed. You still have the `outputStream.close();` right? Do you open any stream when writing headers and data lines?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer i have the workbook declaration XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();, on the service class, so after 1 download the object was already full. so a work aroundi used was in the controller function call i initialized the object again.

workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).